# Solve this trig equation?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\alpha=\sin^{-1}(\sin(\delta)\sin(\varphi)+\cos(\delta)\cos(\varphi)\cos(HRA))$$

Been trying to solve this for awhile now, but going in circles. Can someone please show me how to solve this equation for $\delta$?

Comment: Have I interpreted the symbols `α=sin−1[sinδsinφ+cosδcosφcos(HRA]` correctly?

Comment: Also, what is $HRA$?

Answer (score 1):

"Going in circles" might be a good idea for this question,
since it involves the sine and cosine of the unknown value $\delta$.

Let $x = \cos\delta$ and $y = \sin\delta$. Then 
$$\sin \alpha = y \sin \phi + x \cos \phi \cos(HRA),$$ 
hence
$$y = \frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\phi} - \frac{\cos\phi \cos(HRA)}{\sin\phi}x,$$ 
which is the equation of a line.
We want to find the two intersections of this line with the unit circle,
$x^2 + y^2 = 0.$
If $(x_1,y_1)$ is one such intersection, then one possible value of $\delta$
is

$$\delta = \begin{cases}
\arctan\dfrac{y_1}{x_1} & \text{if}\ x_1 > 0 \\
\arctan\dfrac{y_1}{x_1} + \pi & \text{if}\ x_1 < 0 \\
\pm \dfrac\pi2 & \text{if}\ x_1 = 0.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

by definition we have $\sin^{-1}X=A \iff X=\sin A$, so your equation become:
$$
\sin \alpha=\sin \delta \sin \phi + \cos \delta \cos \phi \cos(HRA)
$$ 
That , for known $\alpha$, $\phi$ and $HRA$ is an  equation of the form:
$$
a=b\sin \delta +c\cos \delta
$$
You can solve this equation using $\cos \delta = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \delta}$: square and be care to improper solutions.